# const/let with another `<script type="module">` block is undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, safari

This works in Chrome and Firefox. Safari gives a console error: `Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: A`.

1. If multiple `script` blocks in HTML file;
2. If at least one of `script` blocks includes `type="module"`

index.html:

```html
<script>
 const A = 'A'
 console.log({ A })
</script>

<script type="module">
 const B = 'B'
 console.log({ A, B })
</script>
```

Comment: It's probably related to the `type="module"` which likely puts that script in a different namespace that doesn't share variables with other `<script>` tags.  You may have to make the shared variables specifically global.

Comment: does safari really crash? Or does it just show the error in the console?

Comment: @cloned sorry! Replaced "crash" with "error"

Comment: @jfriend00 it seems that this is because of const/let implementation on FF/Chrome, where it is not scoped to a `<script>` block.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LEuJNLfLN0 in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const/let` in a `script` (without `type="module"`) are accessible by other scripts in Chrome and Firefox, while unaccessible in Safari.

By replacing `const` with `var` I can avoid my problem, because `var` is scoped globally on all browsers.